# fs.writeFile is not working on my ReactJs / NodeJs app

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to write some stuff in a file using reactJS and nodeJs but it doesnt work. Here is my code, is a simple one and i get that fs.writeFile is not a function. I get this error for each function that i use from fs. In node_module i have the folder for fs but inside i only have package.json and a readme. I dont know what to do, i searched online for answers but nothing. Any help would be awesome

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const fs = require('fs');

export default class WriteFile extends Component {

write = () => {
    fs.writeFile("file.txt", "Hey there!", function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        console.log("The file was saved!");
    }); 
}

render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <button className='btn btn-info' onClick={this.write}>scria-ti-as</button>
    </div>
    )
 }
}
```

and the error

```
TypeError: fs.writeFile is not a function

WriteFile._this.write

D:/js/login_reactjs/src/components/WriteFile.js:8

5 | export default class WriteFile extends Component {

6 | 

7 |     write = () => {

8 |         fs.writeFile("file.txt", "Hey there!", function(err) {

9 |             if(err) {

10 |                 return console.log(err);

11 |             }
```

Comment: Try
import fs from 'fs'
instead of 
const fs = require('fs');

Comment: @S.Haviv now i get this error: TypeError: fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default.a.writeFile is not a function

Comment: How did you create your react app? using create-react-app command?

Comment: yes, that way @S.Haviv

Answer (score 10, accepted):

fs will not work in the browser. This is by design. fs has been stubbed out See [this ticket](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3074)

You would have better luck using packages that support browsers like [browserify](https://github.com/mafintosh/browserify-fs) or [browserFS](https://github.com/jvilk/BrowserFS)

Comment: and what if i have to use some external functions that use file-system?

Comment: @Horatiu123456 use browserify or some similar packages.

Comment: @Horatiu123456 See this [ticket](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3074)

Answer (score 0):

In browser you should use File API to access files - https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Also take a look at https://electronjs.org/ It allows you to use nodejs APIs like fs in you "native"-like react app.