# Stackblitz error loading binary file from project

Tags: javascript, node.js, stackblitz

I'm trying to load a "local" file in a stackblitz project and I'm getting the following error

```
Error: ENOENT: No such file or directory., '/~/small.flb'
```

from this code

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + "/small.flb", function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log(data.toString());
});
```

It seems like it has something to do with the virtualization, if you check the console in this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-yj9vtg?file=index.tsx) you'll see the `small.flb` is not listed (note `./small.flb` doesn't work either w/o `__dirname`)

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but people say that the ability has been [stubbed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55301477/fs-writefile-is-not-working-on-my-reactjs-nodejs-app) by FB, citing [security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003961/react-js-require-fs)...

I will note the behavior on StackBlitz was much different than a create-react-app local implementation, which seem to choke at webpack

I was only trying to set up a testing bed for react/node binary file reads, so I just ended up running a local copy of [ERB](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate)